# Can someone tell me the Complexity of the Addition & Subtraction for the Divide & Conquer Matrix Multiplication algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, complexity-theory, matrix-multiplication

Can someone tell me the Complexity of the Addition & Subtraction for the Divide & Conquer Matrix Multiplication algorithm?

I know that the complexities of addition and subtraction operations of the Classic matrix multiplication are (n^3-n^2) while Strassen’s is 6n^2.81 – 6n^2... but I can't seem to find the Divide & Conquer anywhere.  Just figure if anyone would know, you guys would.  Thanks

Comment: The standard divide and conquer approach is still cubic -- the recurrence relation is `T(n) = 8T(n/2) + O(n^2)`, which is cubic by the master theorem. I don't know the exact constants though, sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Divide & Conquer Matrix Multiplication perform the same amount of additions/subtractions as the Classical Matrix multiplication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355768/does-divide-conquer-matrix-multiplication-perform-the-same-amount-of-additions)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/CS3343/strassen/strassen.html) might help. See the introduction section before the Strassen's Method.